# Javascript push method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

What am I doing wrong here? my array is empty.

```
var infoarray = [{"address":"07288 Albertha Station","city":"Littelside","created_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","id":1,"name":"Mr. Emmitt Emmerich","state":"Missouri","updated_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","zip":"75475-9938"},{MORE INFO}]



 // Populates myarray from infoarray ruby object
      var myarray = new Array();
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $.each(infoarray,function(key,value){
    myarray.push(value['city'])
   });
  });
  console.log(myarray);
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/uqzjQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript is case sensitive, so InfoArray and infoarray are different variables.

Does this work?:

```
var hotelinfo = [{"address":"07288 Albertha Station","city":"Littelside","created_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","id":1,"name":"Mr. Emmitt Emmerich","state":"Missouri","updated_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","zip":"75475-9938"},{MORE INFO}]

 // Populates myarray from infoarray ruby object
      var myarray = new Array();
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $.each(hotelinfo,function(key,value){
    myarray.push(value['city'])
   });
  });
  console.log(myarray);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think

```
InfoArray = var hotelinfo = [{"address":"07288 Albertha Station","city":"Littelside","created_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","id":1,"name":"Mr. Emmitt Emmerich","state":"Missouri","updated_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","zip":"75475-9938"},{MORE INFO}]
```

is valid JavaScript. You'll have to split it:

```
var hotelinfo;
InfoArray = hotelinfo = [{"address":"07288 Albertha Station","city":"Littelside","created_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","id":1,"name":"Mr. Emmitt Emmerich","state":"Missouri","updated_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","zip":"75475-9938"},{MORE INFO}]
```

Comment: This was an error in my transcription between my console and stackoverflow. The infoarray is already the same case as in the funciton. This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive so use

```
$.each(InfoArray,function(key,value){
```

i.e. InforArray is not same as inforarray. Also the line

```
InfoArray = var hotelinfo =
```

should be

```
InfoArray = hotelinfo =
```

Comment: another good point... it's invalid to declare a variable in the middle of an expression.  The var keyword must be at the beginning of a line.  It is perfectly valid to declare multiple variables in a single line, but the var keyword must be the first on the line.

Answer (score 0):

it's invalid to declare a variable in the middle of an expression. The var keyword must be at the beginning of a line. It is perfectly valid to declare multiple variables in a single line, but the var keyword must be the first on the line.